# Why can't I change the subnet IP address in the Virtual Network Editor in VMware Workstation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, ip-address, subnet

In the Virtual Network Editor in VMware Workstation (version 9.0.0 build-812388), I want to change the subnet IP address of one of my host-only virtual networks from `192.168.203.0` to `192.168.124.0` (subnet mask remains 255.255.255.0). The problem is when I change it and press <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd>, it just changes back right away to `192.168.203.0`. How can I change the subnet's IP address?